# PHP-MySQL error inserting data

Tags: php, pdo

How to fix this

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be
>   converted to string in.

My PHP code:

```
$a = $_POST['id'];
$b = $_POST['title'];
$c = $_POST['cat'];
$d = $_POST['cop'];
$e = $_POST['stat'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO books (book_id, book_title, book_category, no_copies, status) VALUES (:a,:b,:c,:d,:e)";
$a = $db->prepare($sql);
$a->execute(array(':a'=>$a, ':b'=>$b, ':c'=>$c, ':d'=>$d, ':e'=>$e));
header('Location: books.php');
```

Comment: [Here's how to bind parameter](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Comment: You overwrite your variable `$a` here: `$a = $db->prepare($sql);` ; Do some basic debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You override your variable `$a`

```
$a = $_POST['id']; // assign here
$a = $db->prepare($sql);// override here
```

Try to give a different name

```
$smt = $db->prepare($sql);
$smt->execute(array(':a'=>$a,':b'=>$b,':c'=>$c,':d'=>$d,':e'=>$e));
header("location: books.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using meaningful names for variables ($stmt instead of $a, for example, which would have avoided the conflict)

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':a'=>$a,':b'=>$b,':c'=>$c,':d'=>$d,':e'=>$e));
```